# Measuring in Print composer and main layer window in QGIS 2.12.3 does not match

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing, scale-bar, qgis-2.12

I work on the municipality level and I am composing print maps with scalebar. I noticed, that length (or scale of my maps) is presented different when items are measured in my main QGIS 2.12.3 layer window and within Print composer. If I measure the football field in my main window, it is 105 m long, which is correct. If I add a scalebar on my map in Print Composer, it shows me that the field is about 112m long. I think, if I had set CRS wrong, my readings would be weird in my main window, but that is not the case. Does anybody has a solution or explanation for noticed difference?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I made print screen with 2.12.0 few days ago but I post my question yesterday, when I realise, 2.12.3 is out. Unfortunatelly, both behave the same. Any ideas? Am I the only one with that kind of problem?

Comment: If you measure the width how does that compare? What units are your CRS in? No info on: http://epsg.io/?q=4765 Are all of your layers directly from EPSG:4765 or are you using some from 3857 that are being re-projected?

Comment: Scalebar is wrong in all directions in my Print composer. I have set QGIS to open all my data with defoult CRS EPSG:4765 as I work mainly with data provided by our state agency, so no reprojection with other CRS is needed. I also noticed that labels, placed in main window to my polygons as Free (are rotated to fit polygon) are plain straight in Print composer ...